# Configuring jersey SpringServlet as a servlet throws "IllegalStateException: No Such servlet"

Tags: spring, servlets, jetty, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

I am attempting to configure the Jersey SpringServlet in the `web.xml` for my Jetty 8 server on Jersey 1.x and when I configure it as a `<servlet>` I get the exception thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Such servlet: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandler.java:1320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.setFilterMappings(ServletHandler.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.addServletMapping(ServletHandler.java:896)
```

Sorry for the short stack trace, I can't copy/paste.

Here is my `web.xml`

```
<!?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>tpm</display-name>

    <context-param>
       <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
       <param-value>prod</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>classpath:spring/tpm-ui-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
       <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
       <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
       <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
       <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
       <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
       <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoadListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
       <filter-name>securityCheckFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>tpm.ui.filter.SecurityCheckFilter</filter-class>
       <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>

    <filter>
       <filter-name>cacheControlFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>tpm.core.rest.filter.ControlFilter</filter-class>
       <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>

    <!-- HERE'S THE PROBLEM, WHEN DECLARED AS A FILTER THE APPLICATION WORKS! -->
    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
          <param-value>tpm.ui.resources</param-value>
       </init-param>

       <!-- WHEN DEFINED AS A FILTER THIS <init-param> IS UNCOMMENTED

       <init-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContexRegex</param-name>
          <param-value>/|/.*(jsp|txt|html|woff|ttf)|/(images|js|swf|css|font|styles|api|(WEB-INF/jsp)|favicon.ico)/.*</param-value>
       -->

       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>securityCheckFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>cacheControlFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

I need to get SpringServlet to work as a Servlet and not a Filter because I am adding another Servlet which is utilizing Comet to perform push services. If I keep SpringServlet as a Filter the request will never get to my new Servlet.

Answer (score 1):

> Note:  [Jetty 8 is EOL](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html) (End of Life), consider upgrading.

That stacktrace makes no sense.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Such servlet: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandler.java:1320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.setFilterMappings(ServletHandler.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.addServletMapping(ServletHandler.java:896)
```

It goes from `addServletMapping` -> `setFilterMappings` -> `updateMappings`

I can find no version of Jetty 8 that had that call path.

*Which version of Jetty 8 are you using?*

Even accounting for the fact that `com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet` implements all of the following interfaces ...

- `javax.servlet.Filter`
- `javax.servlet.Servlet`
- `javax.servlet.ServletConfig`

If we make an assumption that jetty determines the type poorly, there is still no way that call stack would occur.

Went ahead and mocked up a quick test case with a class that implements all 3 of those interfaces and used it against Jetty `8.1.16.v20140903` distribution and it does not trigger that stacktrace.

Perhaps you need to enable full debug logging to see what was happening immediately before that `IllegalStateException` occurred. (its quite likely not the `SpringServlet` init that caused it)

If you have a larger (and more accurate) stacktrace, that might help too.

Comment: Thanks for digging through the source.  (Un)fortunately I can't reproduce the dump since I got past that now, neither can I upgrade beyond Jetty 8.  I think it all boiled down to a mismatch in my pom.xml between my jetty-servlets and spring versions.